# How to install a shower curtain from wall to glass edge?

Tags: shower, product-recommendation, glass

My walk in shower has a glass wall. I'd like to install a shower curtain but I can't find a shower rod that can be secured from a wall to a glass edge.

Here's a picture of the problem.

[image]

Is there a special connector I can buy to secure the shower rod to the glass edge as depicted in the image?

Comment: Don't know of a specific connector (though I do know you can't drill the glass any more, as it's tempered). Have you considered a ceiling mounted shower rod?

Comment: The picture that you posted is very confusing not useful to understanding the nature of your problem. Honestly I think a floor plan sketch would help a lot more then these oblique angle pictures.

Comment: There are fittings which clamp to a glass edge. You might have to obtain one of those and adapt the curtain rod. Or you could hang the rod from the ceiling,. Note that the builder clearly believes  that no curtain is required.

Comment: Yes, we need a better pictures. My gut reaction both aesthetically and practically is that it'd be better to add a glass door to the opening to match.

Comment: Since you already have glass enclosing part of your shower, I would look at installing a glass door to continue the great look you have going on there. There is hardware you can buy that will allow you to attach the hinge to your tiled side. Give this a look: https://www.amazon.com/VRSS-Stainless-Shower-Degree-Glass/dp/B072HF9RLS/ref=sr_1_2_sspa?keywords=glass+door+hinge&qid=1557377864&s=gateway&sr=8-2-spons&psc=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are rods readily available that are held up by tension, such as [this one](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Zenith-43-in-72-in-Tension-Shower-Curtain-Rod-in-Oil-Rubbed-Bronze-505RB/100391617)
[image: shower rod]

The rod is actually made up of two rods, one inside the other. The rod expands in length as you twist the ends. You could bolt a short u-channel to one end that could hold it centered on the edge of the glass.

```
 Images and links are for illustration only, not an endorsement of goods or sources.
```

Comment: Maybe the OP can clarify, but I didn't think there were 2 parallel walls available for the ends of the shower rod.

Comment: It looks like the glass wall is perpendicular to the end wall. The suggestion is to have the rod be perpendicular to the end, in line with the glass wall, hitting its edge.

Comment: It likely wouldn't be too stable with only the edge of the glass supporting one end.

Comment: @DA01 I don't really disagree. This would not be my preferred approach overall.

Comment: My solution was to use the rod as depicted. The tension is good enough to hold a shower curtain.

Answer (score 0):

I would put something like a towel bar installed on your ceiling and then put the shower curtain rings around the bar.  Obviously most towel bars will look dumb like this but a good 10% or so would look fine - and I have a very basic modern one that would look perfect that I have in master bath.